# Drupal 8 Field Plugin With field Type managed_file

Tags: drupal-8

I'm creating a new field type that contains a quote, name, company, and an optional headshot.

My code is below

```
modules/mymodule/src/FieldType/Testimonial.php

<?php

namespace Drupal\dods\Plugin\Field\FieldType;

use Drupal\Core\Field\FieldItemBase;
use Drupal\Core\TypedData\DataDefinition;
use Drupal\Core\Field\FieldStorageDefinitionInterface as StorageDefinition;

/**
 * Plugin implementation of the 'Testimonial' field type.
 *
 * @FieldType(
 *   id = "Testimonial",
 *   label = @Translation("Testimonial"),
 *   description = @Translation("Stores Testimonial Information."),
 *   category = @Translation("Custom"),
 *   default_widget = "TestimonialDefaultWidget",
 *   default_formatter = "TestimonialDefaultFormatter"
 * )
 *
 * Class Testimonial
 * @package Drupal\dods\Plugin\Field\FieldType
 */
class Testimonial extends FieldItemBase
{

/**
 * Field type properties definition.
 *
 * Inside this method we defines all the fields (properties) that our
 * custom field type will have.
 *
 * @param StorageDefinition $storage
 * @return array
 */
public static function propertyDefinitions(StorageDefinition $storage)
{
    $properties['testimonial_quote'] = DataDefinition::create('string')->setLabel(t('Quote'));
    $properties['testimonial_name'] = DataDefinition::create('string')->setLabel(t('Name'));
    $properties['testimonial_company'] = DataDefinition::create('string')->setLabel(t('Company'));
    $properties['testimonial_headshot'] = DataDefinition::create('integer')->setLabel(t('Headshot'));

    return $properties;
}

/**
 * Field type schema definition.
 *
 * Inside this method we defines the database schema used to store data for
 * our field type.
 * @param StorageDefinition $storage
 * @return array
 */
public static function schema(StorageDefinition $storage)
{
    $schema['columns']['testimonial_quote'] = ['type' => 'text'];
    $schema['columns']['testimonial_name'] = ['type' => 'char', 'length' => 100];
    $schema['columns']['testimonial_company'] = ['type' => 'char', 'length' => 100];
    $schema['columns']['testimonial_headshot'] = ['type' => 'int'];

    return $schema;
}

/**
 * Define when the field type is empty.
 *
 * This method is important and used internally by Drupal. Take a moment
 * to define when the field type must be considered empty.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function isEmpty()
{
    return empty($this->get('testimonial_quote')->getValue()) && empty($this->get('testimonial_name')->getValue()) && empty($this->get('testimonial_company')->getValue());
}

}
```

and my widget looks like this

```
modules/mymodule/src/Plugin/Field/FieldWidget/TestimonialDefaultWidget.php

<?php

namespace Drupal\dods\Plugin\Field\FieldWidget;

use Drupal\Core\Field\FieldItemListInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Field\WidgetBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

/**
 * Plugin implementation of the 'TestimonialDefaultWidget' widget.
 *
 * @FieldWidget(
 *   id = "TestimonialDefaultWidget",
 *   label = @Translation("Testimonial Information"),
 *   field_types = {
 *     "Testimonial"
 *   }
 * )
 *
 * Class TestimonialDefaultWidget
 * @package Drupal\dods\Plugin\Field\FieldWidget
 */
class TestimonialDefaultWidget extends WidgetBase
{

/**
 * Define the form for the field type.
 *
 * Inside this method we can define the form used to edit the field type.
 *
 * @param FieldItemListInterface $items
 * @param int $delta
 * @param array $element
 * @param array $form
 * @param FormStateInterface $formState
 * @return array
 */
public function formElement(FieldItemListInterface $items, $delta, array $element, array &$form, FormStateInterface $formState)
{
    $element['testimonial_quote'] = [
        '#type' => 'textarea',
        '#title' => t('Quote'),
        '#default_value' => isset($items[$delta]->testimonial_quote) ? $items[$delta]->testimonial_quote : null,
        '#empty_value' => '',
        '#placeholder' => t('Quote'),
    ];
    $element['testimonial_name'] = [
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('Name'),
        '#default_value' => isset($items[$delta]->testimonial_name) ? $items[$delta]->testimonial_name : null,
        '#empty_value' => '',
        '#placeholder' => t('Name'),
    ];
    $element['testimonial_company'] = [
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('Company'),
        '#default_value' => isset($items[$delta]->testimonial_company) ? $items[$delta]->testimonial_company : null,
        '#empty_value' => '',
        '#placeholder' => t('Company'),
    ];

    $element['testimonial_headshot'] = array(
        '#type' => 'managed_file',
        '#upload_validators' => array(
            'file_validate_extensions' => array('gif png jpg jpeg'),
            'file_validate_size' => array(25600000),
        ),
        '#required' => false
    );

    return $element;
}

}
```

It all looksd fine but when ever i try to save anything I get this error

This value should be of the correct primitive type.

Any ideas would be appreciated I'm hitting a brick wall :(

***UPDATE***

Feels a little hacky but to get this too work I had to do the following

add in formElement()

```
$element['testimonial_headshot_revision'] = [
        '#type' => 'hidden',
        '#default_value' => isset($items[$delta]->testimonial_headshot) ? $items[$delta]->testimonial_headshot : null
    ];
```

add in a new function in the same file like so

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function massageFormValues(array $values, array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
{
    foreach ($values as &$value) {
        if (count($value['testimonial_headshot'])) {
            foreach ($value['testimonial_headshot'] as $fid) {
                $value['testimonial_headshot'] = $fid;
            }
        } else {
            $value['testimonial_headshot'] = $value['testimonial_headshot_revision'] !== '' ? $value['testimonial_headshot_revision'] : '0';
        }

    }

    return $values;
}
```

Comment: Same problem I have faced.

Answer (score 1):

That is because you define `testimonial_headshot` as `int` but provide a file upload widget. As a tip in general: whenever you program "new" stuff, see if you can find something that's similar to what you're trying to do and then just extend/modify it.

Example:
To me, your new field is basically a image field with some extra textfields. So what you could do is look at the ImageItem Field Type and extend it with `testimonial_quote` etc.

So your new field type could look like this:

```
class TestimonialItem extends ImageItem
```

And then:

```
public static function propertyDefinitions(FieldStorageDefinitionInterface $field_definition) {
    // get the image item properties
    $properties = parent::propertyDefinitions($field_definition);

    // if you don't need some properties of the parent do this:
    unset($properties['some_property_of_parent']);

    // add your thing
    $properties['testimonial_quote'] = DataDefinition::create('string')
      ->setLabel(t('Quote'))
      ->setDescription(t("This is the quote of the testimonial"));

    // etc.

    return $properties;
}
```

This is the main idea, do the same for the `schema()` method and also for the widget class. Grab the parent and extend it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi frank, there are actually 3 fields plus an image field, this is also repeatable, currently extending that ImageItem class also repeats those fields again within the image field when the image is uploaded, not the desired outcome.

basically, field1, field2, field 3, image {add more button}

Comment: You can unset the properties of the parent, which you don't need. Like this: unset($properties['something']); The ImageItem itself does this, as it extends the FileItem.

Comment: Thanks Frank I'll give this a go